# How can I react to JEditorPane text changes?

Tags: java, swing, jeditorpane, documentlistener

I'm working to build an editor.  I'd like to know whether the text in `JEditorPane` is modified or not.  How can I react to editor pane text changes?

The following code seems not work.

```
JEditorPane editorConfig = new JEditorPane();

editorConfig.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener(){

    @Override
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        System.out.println("insertUpdate called");
        Dialogc.this.refreshTitle();
    }

    @Override
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        System.out.println("removeUpdate called");
        Dialogc.this.refreshTitle();
    }

    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        System.out.println("changedUpdate");
        Dialogc.this.refreshTitle();
    }               
});
```

Comment: Hi What do you mean by "whether the test in JEditPane is modified or not"? Why does it not work, what is the expected and actual result?

Comment: `I'm working to build a editor` Don't use a JEditorPane. A JEditorPane is used to display HTML. Use a JTextPane. It is easier to work worth plain text and modify attributes if you need those features.

Comment: It should be "whether the TEXT in JEditPane is modified or not" :).

Comment: JTextPane did not work too; KeyLinstener works but can not handle Mouse event.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the title of your question to make it simpler. I also indented your code sample by 4 spaces and removed tab characters so that it renders properly - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. I improved the debugging statements in the printlns. Please describe the steps that you take reproduce your problem, what output you expect to see and what actual output is generated. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks very much for your feedback; the code is right for document update. The code did not work because the document of JTextArea are changed in the coming logic.

Thanks
Klaus